# Migrate from Joomla 2.5.17 to Joomla 3.2.1 Failed

Tags: joomla, migrate, joomla3.2

I am trying to upgrade my website from Joomla 2.5.17 to Joomla 3.2.1.
The website has very few 3rd party extensions.

First I restored my website on my local computer. 
Then I uninstall all the third party extensions and templates.
Then tried to upgrade using one-click Joomla Upgrade manager.
After the upgrade was completed, a blank page was displayed.

Since I did not see any error, I refreshed the page and the below error message was displayed:

Error:

> 1091 Can't DROP 'usertype'; check that column/key exists SQL=ALTER
>   TABLE `xxx_users` DROP KEY `usertype`;

I checked the 'xxx_users' table to see if 'usertype' column existed or not. There was no column named usertype' in the 'xxx_users' table.

When I try to access any menu from the Joomla Administrator section, the following error message is displayed:

Error:

> Notice: Undefined property: InstallerController::$input in
>   E:\xxx\xxx\public_html\administrator\components\com_installer\controller.php
>   on line 39 Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a
>   non-object in
>   E:\xxx\xxx\public_html\administrator\components\com_installer\controller.php
>   on line 39

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of PHP and MySQL are you using?

Comment: PHP - 5.3.5 and MySQL 5.1.44 community

Comment: Why did you uninstall extensions?

Are you comfortable using the command line? You may need to run the deletefiles.php application found in the cli folder.

Answer (score 3):

migrated from 2.5.28 to 3.3.6 and had the same problem

worked with your solution. thank you very much!

Steps done:

1.verified the 2.5.28 version site works correctly

2.deleted the folder "updates" in ./administrator/components/com_admin/sql/
(source: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=825456&start=30#p3108160)

3.upgraded to 3.3.6 with the tool on the administrator page -> got a blank page after it was done :-/

4.created the following database table (the installer couldn't create it somehow):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS #__content_types (
  type_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type_title varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  type_alias varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  table varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  rules text NOT NULL,
  field_mappings text NOT NULL,
  router varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  content_history_options varchar(5120) COMMENT 'JSON string for com_contenthistory options',
  PRIMARY KEY (type_id),
  KEY idx_alias (type_alias)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;`

-- info: replace the #_ with your own database prefix
(source: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=825407#p3103959)

5.accessed: MyWeBpAgE/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&task=database.fix
to fix all remaining database problems
(source: see above ;-))

6.accessed: MyWeBpAgE/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=discover&task=discover.refresh
and updated/installed all extensions

7.I was happy.

Edit:

In the end I found out the module JoomGallery produced these errors at my page.
When I uninstalled it before the Joomla Migration (step 3 from above) it got me no blank page and all database entries were updated correctly.
So how did I migrate from JoomGallery 2.5 to 3 without loosing all categories, etc.?:

1.I didn't uninstall JoomGallery 2.5
2.I executed all explained steps from above
3.I installed JoomGallery 3 over the existing installation
4.voilà, all database entries for the categories, etc. were correctly adopted to the new version :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could always try the link...

your-site-url.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&task=database.fix

...as it sounds like an update has failed, leaving the site in limbo.  This means perhaps you have a partially updated file set and database.  If so, using the above link you can fix the database.  You may also need to fix the files, but this is easier, as you can just upload the files straight from the latest installer, excluding the 'installation' folder, overwriting all existing files.  In some situations, worse-case, I've had to 'discover' the installed but not registered extensions via "Extensions" -> "Extension Manager" -> "Discover" ( your-site-url.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=discover ).

Some background can be found on the following links...

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/&action=&br_trackers_limit=5/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=33177&start=8375

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=825407

http://www.gavick.com/forums/therealdesign/error-while-updating-to-3-2-2-33956.html

Answer (score 0):

Thnx allot for this solution.

Things i have done.

1. delete cdcaptcha plugin & anywhere module (gave me installation problems)
2. deleted the folder "updates" in ./administrator/components/com_admin/sql/
3. upgraded to 3.3.6 with the tool on the administrator page. (Gave me 100.. table errors
4. accessed: /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&task=database.fix
   to fix all remaining database problems
5. accessed: /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=discover&task=discover.refresh
   and updated/installed all extensions
6. Repeated step 4. to make sure everything is ok

Everything works fine now. Thnx again!